# How to apply 1% rate reduction using GST/QST Quick method?

Tags: canada, small-business, sales-tax, hst, quebec

I use [Quick method](https://www.revenuquebec.ca/en/businesses/consumption-taxes/gsthst-and-qst/reporting-qst-and-gsthst/the-quick-method-of-accounting-for-calculating-gst-and-qst-remittances/) for calcualting GST/QST remittances:

> The Quick Method is a simplified accounting method designed to help
>   registrants calculate the GST and QST they must remit to Revenu
>   Québec.
>
> Under the Quick Method of Accounting, you collect GST and QST in the
>   usual manner. However, you need not claim input tax credits (ITCs) and
>   input tax refunds (ITRs) respecting your current operating expenses or
>   purchases made in the course of your commercial activities, because
>   the Quick Method of Accounting takes them into account.
>
> For GST purposes, you need only multiply the total taxable supplies
>   (including GST) by the applicable rate, and for QST purposes, simply
>   multiply the total taxable supplies (including QST) by the applicable
>   rate.
>
> If applicable, you must then calculate the 1% rate reduction on the
>   qualifying portion of your taxable supplies and deduct these partial
>   amounts from the tax payable.

What is not completely clear for me, it's how to apply this 1% reduction.

I understand that I can decrease taxes on 1%, but in the form I need specify remitted GST and QST separately and not sure should I apply this to GST or QST.